# String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote while executing script

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote.

Am trying to execute a jsp script but it's not working for one of the queries that I want to execute.

[image: Error on line 30]

However it's working for following query

```
//query for the report we want to delete
boInfoObjects = boInfoStore.query("Select * From CI_INFOOBJECTS Where SI_PROGID = 'CrystalEnterprise.Webi' AND SI_Name = 'Test_Report_1' and SI_Instance = 0");
```

Comment: The double quotes before `SI_NAME` are ending the string.

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes that are inside the string, because otherwise they act as string delimiters instead of being passed literally as part of the query.

```
WHERE PARENTS(\"SI_NAME='WEBI-UNIVERSE'\", \"SI_NAME ='Ipsoft'\")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with WHERE PARENTS(\"SI_NAME='WEBI-UNIVERSE'\", \"SI_NAME ='Ipsoft'\") and the script is not giving any error now, but when I actually check the output I observed that the delete which should have actually happen has not taken place.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

One is that you seem to be trying to split a string across two lines of code just by putting a `+` at the end of the first line. You have to actually put `"` at the beginning and end of each part and use `+` to join the two parts.

The other is that you are trying to use `"` in the middle of a string, which should obviously make no sense because `"` signals the end of a string. You need to escape the `"` within the string.

This should fix both issues:

```
boInfoObjects = boInfoStore.query("SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS, CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS, CI_APPOBJECTS " +
"WHERE PARENTS(\"SI_NAME='WEBI-UNIVERSE'`", `"SI_NAME='Ipsoft'`") and SI_Instance = 0");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still failing with the same error & same line.

Comment: When I choose this (\"SI_NAME='WEBI-UNIVERSE'\", \"SI_NAME='Ipsoft'\"), this has deleted the reports which I'm aiming, but its deleting the only 1 oldest report. If I just choose to use this query the output is approx 30 reports and I'm hoping it deletes all at once.

Comment: @AmbarishKunte There's nothing in the code you posted that performs deletions. Maybe the problem is in that other part of the code. Are you looping over all the rows returned by the query?